# Finding reachable vertices in directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I'd like to ask about the following problem:

Given a directed graph (not necessarily a DAG), for every vertex v calculate the number of reachable vertices from v.

So using brute force approach (n times DFS) we can get the answer in O(n^2) time complexity. Is there a way to calculate it faster? I can definitely make a DAG from the given graph using SCC. I tried to use previously calculated values, so I could visit each vertex only once, but it does not work at all. The biggest problem lies in a graph like this:

```
  2 -> 1
  3 -> 2
  3 -> 1
  1 -> 4
```

I run a DFS from vertex 1 and return result 1. Then, using it I can immidiately calculate answer for 2 (I do not enter vertex 1 again in second DFS, I use its answer instead), what is 2. Then I get to the vertex 3, and... the algorithm would sum up the result of 1 and 2, since I can reach both of those vertices. But vertex 1 is already calculated in the result for vertex 2. In that way I get the answer equal to 4, which is not true.

Comment: If B is reachable from A, then all nodes reachable from B are also reachable from A. You can make use of this to avoid duplicate traversals.

Comment: Indeed, but I'd have to store each vertex reachable, that would be still O(n^2)

Comment: Not necessarily; you could keep track of how many nodes are reachable from a certain node *as* you perform the first DFS. During subsequent DFS passes, stop as soon as you reach a visited node, and add on the number of nodes reachable from *it*. This way you traverse each node at *most* twice (I think - correct me if you find a contradiction).

Comment: What if there are 2 vertices that are both already visited, but their reachable vertices are completely distinct?

Comment: That doesn't matter because you still iterate through all nodes in the graph, but the point is each DFS traversal performed from a node reduces the set of nodes which still need to traversed.

Comment: I feel you don't get it. Try this graph: 3 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2-> 7, 4 -> 5, 6 -> 4, 6 - > 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really suspect that there isn't a known better algorithm for general graphs. All the papers I found on the subject [1] [2] describe algorithms that run in O(|V| * |E|) time.

The wikipedia page [3] says the fastest algorithms reduce the problem to matrix multiplication.

[1] http://ion.uwinnipeg.ca/~ychen2/conferencePapers/tranRelationCopy.pdf

[2] http://www.vldb.org/conf/1988/P382.PDF

[3] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#Algorithms

Answer (score 3):

I think the best algorithm run **O(|V| * |E|)**.

Algorithm:

1 - Do *SCC* to the graph.

2 - Build reduced graph *Gr*.

3 - Run one *dfs* for each vertex *v* in *Gr* and for each visited different *SCC* (including the *SCC* of *v*) accumulate the amount of vertex in them (precalculated from step 1).

With this algorithm you eliminate the **|V|*|V|** factor from brute force **O(|V| * |V| + |V| * |E|))**.

This is the best and simple algorithm that I know for this problem. I have no demonstration but I'm pretty sure there's no better way.